# Probability question with before and after scenario

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Two shops have cupcakes. Shop $A$ have $2$ blue cupcakes and $3$ chocolate cupcakes. Shop $B$ has $2$ blue cupcakes and $5$ chocolate cupcakes. Suppose we randomly choose a cupcake from $A$ and transfer it to $B$. What is the probability that the cupcake we choose is blue from $B$?

My attempt at this was to say that there are two cases:

1. If a chocolate cupcake was transferred then we would have $8$ total cupcakes at shop $B$, so choosing a chocolate cupcake is $\frac{5}{8}$.
2. If a blue cupcake was transferred then we still have $8$ total cupcakes at shop $B$, so choosing a blue cupcake becomes $\frac{2}{8}$.

All together we have: $\frac{3}{8}\cdot \frac{2}{7} + \frac{2}{8} \cdot \frac{5}{7} = \frac{2}{7}$.

Is this the correct way to think about this problem?

Comment: I don't understand  your calculation.  Where do all the $7's$ come from?  $A$ starts with $5$ cupcakes, so I'd have expected to see some $5's$ but not $7's$ in the denominators.

Comment: I thought the $7$'s are from before the transfer... Should the probability the change a blue cupcake is taken from $A$?

Comment: The question is not clear to me: Is it that the cupcake is blue given cupcake is originally from B or something else? Have you translated the exercise?

Comment: @callculus, we randomly choose a cupcake from $A$ and transfer it to $B$. So the cupcake is either blue or chocolate.

Comment: @DippyDog I know. But the question is not clear to me.

Comment: @callculus  the question is poorly phrased.  I read it as "first you choose a cupcake uniformly at random from $A$ and give it to $B$.  Then you choose a cupcake uniformly at random from $B$.  What is the probability that this final cupcake is blue?"

Comment: @DippyDog  The prior distribution in $B$ is not directly relevant.  All that matters is the distribution in $A$ and the final distribution in $B$.

Comment: Agree with @lulu, that is what my answer assumes.

Comment: @lulu Thanks. Yes, the was my first idea as well. But I wasn´t sure. DippyDog should rephrase it. My suggestion: *A cupcake is finallly chosen from shop B. What is the probability that this cupcake is blue?* But I´m still not sure if not something else is meant.

Comment: @callculus  And I could have it wrong. But I can't come up with anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  we first randomly choose a cupcake from A and transfer it to B, we can say we transfer
$\frac{2}{5}$blue + $\frac{3}{5}$ chocolate cupcakes.

If we then randomly choose a cupcake from B, then  the probability that the cupcake being blue  is $\frac{2.4}{8}$ = 30%.